# Combine two Cloudwatch insights queries

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have two Cloudwatch insights queries that I would love to be able to run side by side and compare the results of both two.

```
stats count(*) as requestIdCount by @requestId 
| filter @message like /START RequestId/
| filter requestIdCount > 1
```

```
stats count(*) as requestIdCount by @requestId 
| filter @message like /END RequestId/
| filter requestIdCount > 1
```

It would be great to be able to do

```
fields (
    stats count(*) as requestIdCount by @requestId 
    | filter @message like /END RequestId/
    | filter requestIdCount > 1) as EndRequestCount,
       (
    stats count(*) as requestIdCount by @requestId 
    | filter @message like /START RequestId/
    | filter requestIdCount > 1) as StartRequestCount
```

But I don't see any way to do subqueries in insights right now. Is there a method to combine queries like this?

Comment: I would like to know how I can to do it too :)

Comment: I am in the club. I need to do it and I have no idea

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
parse @message 'START RequestId' as @startRequestId
    | parse @message 'END RequestId' as @endRequestId
    | stats count(@startRequestId) as startRequestIdCount , count(@endRequestId) as endRequestIdCount by bin(5m)
    | filter startRequestIdCount > 1
    | filter endRequestIdCount > 1
```

[CloudWatch Logs Insights Query Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html)

Comment: exactly what I needed, thank you!! This works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

You can create a logic via API or CLI in order to use the output of a query as the input of another query

- [Amazon CloudWatch Logs API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)
- [AWS CLI Command Reference - logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/index.html#cli-aws-logs)

It works as a script where you make a request, interpret the results, and then issue another requests with the results of the first one. It's a bit more work but I'm not aware of another way to do so